# Check if img src is empty using jQuery attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying the following code:

```
            if(!$('img.photoPreview', this).attr('src') == '') {
                    alert('empty src...');
            }
```

but it errors in the editor as not being completed correctly.

Can someone advise what is wrong?

Note: I'm trying to check - if not this image src is empty...

thx

Comment: Would be helpful to know the error..

Comment: Also you're checking it on two different object concurrently , are they strongly connected?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Placing the ! at the start negates the $('img...') not the whole expression. Try:

```
if ($('img.photoPreview', this).attr('src') != '') {
    alert('empty src');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`!` operator will be evaluated before the result (boolean) returned from `==` operator and will be applied to object returned by selector instead of `boolean` returned by `==` operator.

Change

```
if(!$('img.photoPreview', this).attr('src') == '')
```

To

```
if($('img.photoPreview', this).attr('src') != '')
```

Answer (score 4):

It's due to "src" being undefined. You should use this (it's more efficient than != ""):

```
if(!$('img.photoPreview', this).attr('src')) {
     alert('empty src...');
}
```

You can see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/GKHvQ/

Answer (score 3):

@adil & @scoot

```
if($('img.photoPreview', this).attr('src') != '')
```

this condition says that if attribute src is not blank. But the condition would be to check if src attribute is ''.

better will be to use

```
if($('#photoPreview').attr('src') == '') {
 alert('empty src...');
}
```